# char* in structs not being free()'d by cleanUp function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I've read that the rule when using malloc() is to always have a matching free(). If malloc() is used 7 times in a program, there must be a corresponding number of free()s. However, this does not seem to be working for several char* I've malloc'd inside of a struct. The struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char* ID;
    char* PassWord;
}Account, *pAccount, **ppAccount;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int numAccounts;
    ppAccount accounts;
}Collection,*pAccountCollection;
```

The mallocs (function simplified):

```
void AddNewAccount(pAccountCollection e){
    int string_length = sizeof(char)*26;
    pAccount newAct = malloc(sizeof(Account));

    newAct->ID = malloc(string_length);
    newAct->PassWord = malloc(string_length);
    e ->numAccounts++;

    e->accounts[e->numAccounts-1] = newAct;
}
```

And finally, the cleanup called at the end:

```
void CleanUp(pAccountCollection e){
unsigned int i;

    if(e->numAccounts != 0){
        for (i = 0; i < e->numAccounts; i++){
            free(e->accounts[i]->ID);
            free(e->accounts[i]->PassWord);
            free(e->accounts[i]);
        }
        free(e->accounts);
    }
}
```

I'm checking for leaks with

```
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF|_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
```

And it's flagging the ID and PassWord of newAct as 26 bytes not being freed.

```
 Detected memory leaks!
 Dumping objects ->
 {73} normal block at 0x006F9268, 26 bytes long.
   Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
 {72} normal block at 0x006F45E8, 26 bytes long.
   Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
```

If I free them at the end of the fuction like so:

```
void AddNewAccount(pAccountCollection e){
    int string_length = sizeof(char)*26;
    pAccount newAct = malloc(sizeof(Account));

    newAct->ID = malloc(string_length);
    newAct->PassWord = malloc(string_length);

    e->accounts[e->numAccounts-1] = newAct;
    free(newAct->ID);
    free(newAct->PassWord);
}
```

I lose the reference to that account in the collection of accounts AccountCollection e.

Any insight?

Comment: Hint: You can omit the condition `e->numAccounts != 0` in the `CleanUp`-Function, as the for loop would be skipped anyway in that case (`0 < 0` is always false...).

Comment: Just as an aside: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition -- the unit of sizeof is char.

Comment: Do not `typedef` pointers! This obfuscates the semantics and is hard to read and maintain. Only `typedef` the underlying type and use the `*` explicitly.

Comment: I cannot see a problem in your posted code, which makes me wonder whether the problem was edited away for this posting. Hence my suggestion is to boil your original code down until the error is obvious or goes away in an editing step, giving a hint as to where it is. What I find suspicious is that the leak concerns only the members of the struct, not the struct itself. Did you "manually" set up an account somewhere which is not in your standard account collection? (And therefore is never freed?)

Comment: How   `pAccountCollection e` that you pass to `CleanUp` is being declared in your code?

Comment: I've just realised; the data it reports as being in the "leaked" objects isn't ever actually initialised. Are you sure it's the code posted causing the leak? Is there any error handling that can cause an early exit from `AddNewAccount`? How do you assign actual values to `newAct->ID` and `newAct->PassWord`?

Answer (score 5):

Your `AddNewAccount` function never increments `e->numAccounts`, and so `CleanUp` always acts as though the `Collection` contains no accounts, and so does nothing.

Comment: I simplified the code too much in putting it up. numAccounts++ is in the code. Editted.